# specify destination for CTestTestfile.cmake

Tags: cmake, ctest

When executing `cmake` to generate `ctest` inputs, how can I directly specify the destination directory for the `cmake`-generated `CTestTestfile.cmake`? Specifically, my test suite is an independent cmake project. I currently add it to the main `cmake` project with `include()`, but the more appropriate method is to use `add_subdirectory()`. However, `add_subdirectory()` installs `CTestTestfile.cmake` in the subproject's directory in the `build` directory, but I need it in `build/` for `ctest` to find it.

I set up the test macros in a file `CTestList.cmake` which lives in the test_project. This file is included in the build in `test_project/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include(CTest)
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/CTestList.cmake)
```

With `include()`:

```
project/
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- src/
|-- test_project/
`-- build/
    |-- CTestTestfile.cmake
    `-- test_project/
```

With `add_subdirectory()`:

```
project/
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- src/
|-- test_project/
`-- build/
    `-- test_project/
        `-- CTestTestfile.cmake
```

Comment: Can you show us those parts of your code which generate the `CTestTestfile.cmake`?

Comment: I have `CTestList.cmake` which handles all of the input argument prep to my test execution scripts. `CTestList.cmake` ultimately calls the cmake command `add_test()`. In `test_project/CMakeLists.txt`, I include `CTestList.cmake`

Comment: @Akira thanks for your response. I updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`include`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include.html) and the [`add_subdirectory`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_subdirectory.html) commands of `CMake` are very different.

While the `include` command works like `#include` of C and C++ – loads the content of included file into the file where it appears –, the `add_subdirectory` adds a subdirectory to the build. This means that when you use the `add_subdirectory` the variables inside the subdirectory's `CMakeLists.txt` will be the part of a different scope and the value of [`CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR.html) variable will be different too. Just add the following line to the `test_project/CMakeLists.txt` and try either to `include` it or add it by `add_subdirectory`:

```
message(STATUS "The files will be generated into: " ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

The [`enable_testing`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/enable_testing.html) enables testing for current directory and below. So, when you used the `add_subdirecory` instead of `include` the *current directory* meant `build/test_project/` – as explained above.

To make sure the `CTestTestfile.cmake` will be created in `build` directory too, simply add an extra `enable_testing` command to the top-level `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: thanks for the great explanation. Its worth noting for future reference that `include(CTest)` calls `enable_testing` in addition to adding a few new targets for cdash submission. But the main point here is the point at which `enable_testing` is called in cmake. Subtle but big.